# Low pass filter with different non linear phases

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter

I want to design low pass filters with different non linear phases. Means the magnitude response of all low pass filters will be same but having different non linear phases.

Answer (score 2):

1. Design your desired magnitude response
2. Make it minimum phase
3. Cascade with any type of allpass filter to create your desired phase response